# Error: Set the experimentalDecorators option to remove this warning

Tags: cypress, javascript-decorators

I'm using Cypress version 3.3.1. I'm getting the following error:

> Error: "TS1219: Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning."

PS: I've set `"experimentalDecorators": true` in `tsconfig.json`.
Tried the following but it didn't work: https://github.com/cypress-io/eslint-plugin-dev/issues/4

Code where the error is being reported:

```js
@observable public someVar: dataType;
```

Comment: Do you know a Cypress doc page where its available decorators are listed and described? I didn't find any with https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cypress+javascript+or+js+decorator+site%3Acypress.io

Answer (score 1):

I created the `tsconfig.json` under the test directory, i.e. `my_project/__tests__/integration/tsconfig.json` and set the `experimentalDecorators` as `true`.

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```